# How to Scroll WPF ListBox Programmatically One Item Up?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scroll

I have a `ListBox`, in WPF, that I load songs, artists, albums and playlists into.

When I click the artists button, for example, I populate the list box with each artist.

When I click an artist, it loads the songs for that artist. Same for albums.

There are up and down buttons to scroll through the list box, which auto select entries and scroll up and down as follows:

```
private void FileNavDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaList.SelectedIndex < MediaList.Items.Count)
    {
        MediaList.SelectedIndex++;
        MediaList.ScrollIntoView(MediaList.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Perhaps you see my problem already. I can't scroll through my artists, albums or playlists with these buttons, as they autoselect the next entry, which then populates the songs.

You're thinking it should be simple to just not select it when I'm in artist's category, and then scroll into view the selected item + 1, and sure, that does work, but then when scrolling up, since the immediately above entry is already in view, scroll into view does nothing visible to the user. I have to click up five times before it scrolls into view the entry that's 5 entries up, which was out of view before.

So, simple fix? I don't want to change the structure too much, perhaps I just need something to detect if the view scrolled at all. If it didn't, I can increment/decrement the scroll index again, and scroll it into view until it changed.

Comment: how many items are visible in your `Listbox` and which on is your Selected one  before you click on your `Button`?

Comment: 5 at a time, total number in the listbox could be 1 to 100.

Comment: And none is selected. That's the thing. I'm trying to scroll the listbox contents up or down by 1 element.

Comment: ok now i know your problem "you think wrong" :) because if you start your selectedIndex is -1 by default now comes your first click index goes up to 0 but you are still in the view able part of your list, next click now index becomes 1 still same situation, .....